# can't install paperclip rails 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am still new to rails 3 and the different commands to use in terminal. I have tried to use the $ rails plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git command but everytime I hit enter, it just brings up my options when I use rails new, like -v tell your the version or -b is the builder. I don't know whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the above, gem is the way to go. Just add to you Gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.3'
```

and run:

```
bundle install
```

Should be as easy as that to get paperclip running. Don't forget to include the 3 migration parts when binding to a model (example for video). In this case I am adding paperclip as 'attachment' to my Video model. Just slap 'file_name', 'content_type', and 'file_size' to the end of the downcased attribute:

```
class AddVideoAttachment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :videos, :attachment_file_name, :string
    add_column :videos, :attachment_content_type, :string
    add_column :videos, :attachment_file_size, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :videos, :attachment_file_size
    remove_column :videos, :attachment_content_type
    remove_column :videos, :attachment_file_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install Paperclip as a gem, not as a plugin. Installing as a plugin can lead to all sorts of issues.

GitHub paperclip sites states specifically:
**"Paperclip is distributed as a gem, which is how it should be used in your app. It's technically still installable as a plugin, but that's discouraged, as Rails plays well with gems."**

Visit [GitHub/Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and install Paperclip as a gem and you should be fine.